# Bind selectedItems of Multicombobox in custom control UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'd like to bind selectedItems that comes from JsonModel in controller to the custom control.

Custom control

```
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/Control',
  'sap/m/MultiComboBox',
  ], function (Control, MultiComboBox) {
  return Control.extend('drex.control.TokenizedMultiComboBox', {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        selectedKeys: { type: 'string[]', defaultValue: [] }
      },
      aggregations: {
        combo: { type: 'sap.m.MultiComboBox', multiple: false },
      },
    },

    init: function (allItems) {
      Control.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    onAfterRendering: function() {
      const combo = this.getAggregation('combo');
      const selectedKeys = this.getSelectedKeys();
      if (selectedKeys.length) {
        combo.setSelectedKeys([selectedKeys]);
      }
    },

    renderer: function (rm, oControl) {
      rm.write('<div');
      rm.writeControlData(oControl);
      rm.write('>');
      rm.write('<div>');
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('combo'));
      rm.write('</div>');
      rm.write('</div>');
    },
  })
})
```

XML

```
<drex:TokenizedMultiComboBox
    selectedKeys="{selectedItems>/disease}" />
```

where `selectedItems>/disease` is defined in controller:

```
this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(), 'selectedItems');
```

The problem is that this the Multicombobox in custom control doesn't include any values of selectedItems.

Comment: `this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(), 'selectedItems');` is an empty model, right?

Comment: @D.Seah initialy yes, but as items are selected it will be populated by selected keys.

Comment: thanks. I kind of understand what you want to do and it is not simple because you have to synchronous the selected keys in the combo box and the selectedKeys property that you have. E.g. what happen when user select/deselect an item. you have to listen to the selectionChange event and update the selectedKeys property; you also have to listen for the changes in the selectedKeys property as it is bound to a model. The model can change after onAfterRendering function is called.

Comment: @D.Seah could you check my answer below, that solved an issue as it seems

Comment: please do a few little tests. check with model "selectedItems" values for /disease after onAfterRendering method is called. You can setTimeout 3 seconds. See if the combobox values changes; and also select and deselect the values in combobox and check if model values changes. Then you are good :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an answer thanks to [How can I set Selected items in a sapui5 MultiComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732452/how-can-i-set-selected-items-in-a-sapui5-multicombobox)

```
...
metadata: {
      properties: {
        selectedKeys: { type: 'string', defaultValue: '' }
      },
      aggregations: {
        combo: { type: 'sap.m.MultiComboBox', multiple: false },
      },
    },

onAfterRendering: function() {
      const combo = this.getAggregation('combo');
      const selectedKeys = this.getSelectedKeys();
      combo.bindProperty('selectedKeys', selectedKeys);
    }
...
```

I am passing the model path as string now.
XML

```
<drex:TokenizedMultiComboBox
    selectedKeys="selectedItems>/disease" />
```

Hope this is a correct appoach..